# What are the flags/banners on the hills for?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I haven't played Fortnite Battle Royale for a while and hopped onto it yesterday. There has been a few changes since I last played but one that I can't seem to work out are the banners on top of the hills. When you go to them it replaces a default hovering banner with yours and sticks into the ground. Other than showing others your banner I'm not entirely sure what they are for.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The banners on the mountain tops are linked to a challenge that comes with the battle pass. You go to them and collect them, after which you will gain 5 battle stars as a result. This is only important if you own the battle pass.

This was introduced in week 6. I have added [a link](https://www.gamesradar.com/fortnite-battle-royale-battle-pass-challenges-guide/2/) that shows you where they are and what they "Do" so you can get a better picture.

Comment: I found an similar article myself and was just writing an answer up, this appears to be correct thanks :)